# Unable to Push Notifications to the users on using FCM on write event inside the firebase realtime database in android

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hello everyone I'm new to [[image]firebase](/questions/tagged/firebase)

I'm facing a problem in my android app 
the problem is that I'm trying to make cloud function that will be invoked **whenever there is a change in the node of my realtime firebase database** and inform all the user about that change though a notification.

These are the firebase logs of the error that I'm getting.

[image]

```js
// imports firebase-functions module
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
// imports firebase-admin module
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

/* Listens for new messages added to /messages/:pushId and sends a notification to subscribed users */

exports.pushNotification = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}').onWrite(( change,context) => {
console.log('Push notification event triggered');

/* Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database */

    const valueObject = change.after.val();
    
/* Create a notification and data payload. They contain the notification information, and message to be sent respectively */ 

    const payload = {
        notification: {
            "title": 'App Name',
            "body": "New message",
            "sound": "default"
        },
        data: {
            title: valueObject.title,
            messagge: valueObject.messagge
        }
    };

    /* Create an options object that contains the time to live for the notification and the priority. */
    const options = {
        priority: "high",
        timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24 //24 hours
    };
return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("notifications", payload, options).then(function(response){
         console.log('Notification sent successfully:',response);
    }) 
    .catch(function(error){
         console.log('Notification sent failed:',error);
    });
    }
);
```

Comment: try Just

admin.initializeApp();

Comment: i tried, but no change in the logs